# Image processing of a 3 by 3 window

Tags: matlab

How do I select a 3 by 3 window from an image and find mean of it? Is there any built-in function for it in a MATLAB toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use the conv2 function with the mean convolution filter.

```
res = conv2(I, ones(3,3) .* 1/9);
```

Given that I is a grayscale image.